# Audio does not work in android studio (MediaPlayer)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio, media-player

I have a simple program in android studio with one button to play an audio file. However, the audio does not work when I press the button.

PS. I use the emulator

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.out);

        Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried playing the audio file elsewhere ie do you know it plays sound?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
MediaPlayer  mediaPlayer = Create(this, R.raw.out);
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the media volume is set to 0 (not the ringer volume). You can set it by:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
```

Comment: MediaPlayer  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Activity.this,R.raw.a1);
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new musicCompletionListener());
mediaPlayer.start();
private class musicCompletionListener implements OnCompletionListener {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
mediaPlayer.reset();// stops any current playing song
mediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), resourceID);
mediaPlayer.start(); // starting mediaplayer
```

another option is that instead of placing your file in raw folder you can just put it in the assets folder and  play it using `AssetManager`